# Arch Nginx Uwsgi no app loaded

Tags: arch-linux, python, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to get django working but uwsgi is having problems loading anything. Most likely do to my ignorance. I would love some help troulble shooting. I have been looking at similar posts on the stack exchange but none of them have helped, they are all pretty specific.

In `/etc/uwsgi/` I have a `.ini` file for config and a `.py` file that I want `uwsgi` to host on port `2929`.

At `/etc/uwsgi/test.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:2929
plugin=python
wsgi-file=/etc/uwsgi/test.py
master=True
```

At `/etc/uwsgi/test.py`:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

At `/etc/nginx/sites/test.conf`, which is enabled and loaded into nginx:

```
upstream test_uwsgi{                          
 server 127.0.0.1:2929;
}
server{
 listen 80;
 server_name test.example.com;
 location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass test_uwsgi;
 }
}
```

**Note:** I am using Arch Linux.

I restart `nginx`, then start `test.ini` using uwsgi:

```
systemctl restart nginx
systemctl start uwsgi@test
```

Both succeed to run/activate without error. When I check the log/journal for the service uwsgi@test.service:

```
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI service unit...
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/test.ini
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.13.1 (64bit) on [Fri Sep 30 11:29:23 2016] ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: compiled with version: 6.1.1 20160501 on 01 June 2016 05:45:41
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: os: Linux-4.7.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Aug 20 23:02:56 CEST 2016
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: nodename: Nexus
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: machine: x86_64
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: clock source: unix
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: pcre jit disabled
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: detected number of CPU cores: 4
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: current working directory: /
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: your processes number limit is 28969
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:2929 fd 4
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:46:01)  [GCC 6.1.1 20160602]
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: Python main interpreter initialized at 0xcbfb40
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** Operational MODE: single process ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: unable to find "application" callable in file /etc/uwsgi/test.py
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 576)
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus uwsgi[576]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 590, cores: 1)
Sep 30 11:29:23 Nexus systemd[1]: Started uWSGI service unit.
Sep 30 11:29:26 Nexus uwsgi[576]: -- unavailable modifier requested: 14 --
Sep 30 11:29:26 Nexus uwsgi[576]: -- unavailable modifier requested: 14 --
```

I think the key line in this whole log is:

```
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

UWSGI cannot find the python file?

How do I get this working?

Any assistance is much appreciated!